# Replace elements of 2 arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have 2 arrays: 
`var underArray = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]` and `var letterArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]`. I also have a button, and every time I press a button I want to replace an element of `underArray` to one from `letterArray`.

For exmple:

- First Press: `var underArray = [A, _, _, _, _]`
- Second Press: `var underArray = [A, B, _, _, _]`
- Third Press: `var underArray = [A, B, C, _, _]`
  etc...

I can do it manually like: `underArray[0] = letterArray[0]` , `underArray[1] = letterArray[1]`, but that's not an option.

---

So far I tried creating a for - loop , but it did not work:

```
     @IBAction func myButtons(sender: UIButton) {


    for var index = 0; index < underArray.count; ++index {
    swap(&underArray[index], & letterArray[index])
    }
 }
```

I suspect it's a wrong approach. What would be a right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare your variables out of your IBAction and make sure you don't do anything in case the button has been pressed too many times:

```
var pressCounter = 0
var underArray = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
var letterArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

@IBAction func myButtons(sender: UIButton) {

    if pressCounter<underArray.count {
        swap(&underArray[pressCounter], &letterArray[pressCounter])
    }
    // lets increment +1 (the button has been pressed)
    pressCounter++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a integer variable to be a counter (initialized to 0), and every time you press the button, you do the following:
1. swap(&underArray[counter], & letterArray[counter])
2. increment counter